# Scrolling sidebar inside a div with scrollbar - $(window).on('scroll', function()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my social sidebar make scroll only within the gray div. I have already put the sidebar within the gray div does not exceed the footer or the content above. My difficulty is to sidebar scroll accompanying the scroll without going gray div.

http://test.eae.pt/beautyacademy/angebot/

**JS:**

```
beautyAcademy.sharer = {
element: void 0,
elementToScroll: void 0,
init:function() {
    this.element = $('.js-sharer-ref');
    console.log(this.element.length);
    if(this.element.length != 1) {
        return;
    }
    this.build();
},
build: function() {
    this.binds();
},
binds: function() {
    var _this = this;
    // Element that's gonna scroll
    this.$elementToScroll = $('.fixed-social');

    // Element that's gonna scroll height
    this.elementToScrollHeight = this.$elementToScroll.outerHeight();

    // Element where scroll is gonna happen Height
    this.elementHeight = this.element.outerHeight();

    // Element where scroll is gonna happen distance to top
    this.elementOffsetTop = this.element.offset().top;

    // Scroll that was done on the page
    this.windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    this.elementOffsetBottom = this.elementOffsetTop + this.elementHeight - this.elementToScrollHeight;

    this.$elementToScroll.css('top', (_this.elementOffsetTop+80) + "px");

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
       if(this.windowScrollTop +  this.elementToScrollHeight < this.elementHeight  )
           this.$elementToScroll.css('margin-top',  this.windowScrollTop );
    });
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try like below :

```
 $(function(){
   if ($('#container').length) {
      var el = $('#container');
      var stickyTop = $('#container').offset().top; // returns number
      var stickyHeight = $('#container').height();

      $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
          var limit = $('#footer').offset().top - stickyHeight - 20;

          var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

          if (stickyTop < windowTop){
             el.css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0 });
          }
          else {
             el.css('position','static');
          }

          if (limit < windowTop) {
          var diff = limit - windowTop;
          el.css({top: diff});
          }
        });
   }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/eyxd9y83/)

Comment: But if i use position fixed the sidebar touch footer , I only want scroll inside a gray div with page